Value remains null when I select a dropdown in Blazor
<div class="form-floating mb-3">
    <select class="form-control" @bind="Input.SelectedGradeId">
        <option value="">Select Grade</option>
        @if (Input?.Grades != null)
        {
            @foreach (var grade in Input.Grades)
            {
                <option value="@grade.Id">
                    @grade.Id - @grade.Level
                </option>
            }
        }
    </select>
    <label for="grade" class="form-label">Grade</label>
    <ValidationMessage For="() => Input.SelectedGradeId" class="text-danger" />
    <p>selected grade = @Input.SelectedGradeId</p>
</div>

<div class="form-floating mb-3">
    <InputSelect class="form-control" @bind-Value="Input.SelectedOrgUnitId">
        <option value="">Select Org Unit</option>
        @if (Input?.OrgUnits != null)
        {
            @foreach (var orgUnit in Input.OrgUnits)
            {
                <option value="@orgUnit.Id">
                    @orgUnit.Id - @orgUnit.UnitName
                </option>
            }
        }
    </InputSelect>
    <label for="org-unit" class="form-label">Org Unit</label>
    <ValidationMessage For="() => Input.SelectedOrgUnitId" class="text-danger" />
    <p>selected org.unit = @Input.SelectedOrgUnitId</p>
</div>

when i select a dropdown the value is remain null which cause the form cannot be submitted.
private sealed class InputModel
{
    [Required]
    [Display(Name = "Grade")]
    public int SelectedGradeId { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [Display(Name = "Organization/Unit")]
    public int SelectedOrgUnitId { get; set; }

    public List<Grade> Grades { get; set; } = new List<Grade>();
    public List<OrgUnit> OrgUnits { get; set; } = new List<OrgUnit>();
}

this is the model
when i try to submit it for the first time it says there's problem with the foreign key but when i tried to insert the value manually from ssms it is successfully updated so its certain theres no problem within the database relation.
but when i add a validator below:
private async Task OnValidSubmitAsync()
{
    Console.WriteLine($"Selected Grade ID: {Input.SelectedGradeId}");
    Console.WriteLine($"Selected Org Unit ID: {Input.SelectedOrgUnitId}");


    // Validation against the database
    var selectedGrade = await DbContext.Grades.FindAsync(Input.SelectedGradeId);
    var selectedOrgUnit = await DbContext.OrgUnit.FindAsync(Input.SelectedOrgUnitId);

    if (selectedGrade == null)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Invalid Grade selected.");
        RedirectManager.RedirectToCurrentPageWithStatus("Error: Invalid Grade selected.", HttpContext);
        return;
    }

    if (selectedOrgUnit == null)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Invalid Org Unit selected.");
        RedirectManager.RedirectToCurrentPageWithStatus("Error: Invalid Org Unit selected.", HttpContext);
        return;
    }

    // Update user profile
    user.GradeId = Input.SelectedGradeId;
    user.OrgUnitId = Input.SelectedOrgUnitId;

    var updateResult = await UserManager.UpdateAsync(user);
    if (!updateResult.Succeeded)
    {
        RedirectManager.RedirectToCurrentPageWithStatus("Error: Failed to update profile.", HttpContext);
        return;
    }

    await SignInManager.RefreshSignInAsync(user);
    RedirectManager.RedirectToCurrentPageWithStatus("Your profile has been updated", HttpContext);
}

it said that i cant submit it because the selected item is invalid, so it maybe because the returned value is null.
i've try to use @onchange, @bind-Value, InputSelect component but it still doesnt work. and i've ensure that the data type is accordant.

You're getting null values for both select and inputSelect?

yes, i've tried both and still getting null

please include your ValidSubmit code

sure, i've added it

On the assumption that this is Net8, what rendermode are you using and where did you set Interactivity [Global or Per Page/Component]?  How is your EditForm defined?  It would be really good if you produce a [MRE] that demonstrates the problem - rather that one of us having to build one to try and reproduce the problem!

By default, components use static server-side rendering (static SSR). You probably just add the line @rendermode InteractiveServer:
@page "/xxx"
@rendermode InteractiveServer

//the EditForm and the rest

If you do not want to change the rendermode, you need use [SupplyParameterFromForm] attribute and add the name for <select>:
<select class="form-control" name="Input.SelectedGradeId" @bind="Input.SelectedGradeId">
</select>
[SupplyParameterFromForm]

private InputModel Input { get; set; } = new InputModel();

